# Markdown Table in Postman documentation not rendered properly in newman-htmlextra file

Tags: postman, markdown, newman

I am using newman with htmlextra to run a Postman collection and generate an html report.

I have used a table within the Postman documentation section which is in Markdown format, something like this :

| CODE | STATUS | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | success |  |
| 404 | no_data_found | No saved report found for the logged-in user |

It renders properly in Postman

However, when I open the htmlextra report, it looks something like this :

[htmlextra report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v7Ml.png)

Has someone come across this issue before?
Any ideas would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Postman and the reporter use 2 different markdown rendering engines. Can you raise an issue on the repo so I can look closer at the problem. If you can provide a collection file, I would be able to run that locally.

Comment: @DannyDainton I will raise an issue on the repo. I am not sure I can provide the collection file as it will involve company data. Is there anything else that will help?

Comment: Just create a new empty collection and add the same markdown table description, I don't really care about the other stuff, just the thing that's causing the problem. 

Comment: @DannyDainton will do :D

Comment: https://github.com/DannyDainton/newman-reporter-htmlextra/issues/322 - Issue raised in repo @DannyDainton